# Pressure coefficient on fluid mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I have to solve numerically a fluid mechanics problem. I have an airfoil with a flap deployed downwards, under the airfoil I have set a mesh with some nodes. I have already computed stream function values ( $\psi$) on every node, and velocity values ( $V$ ) on every node.

But, there is another thing I must compute the **pressure coefficient**. I know that the equation is:

$$CP = 1 - \left( \dfrac{V(i,j)} {V_\infty} \right) ^2$$

Where $V(i,j)$ is the velocity at every node of the mesh, and $V_\infty$ is the velocity far away from the airfoil.

My trouble is that I don't know **how to determine the value of $V_{\infty}$**. They state on the problem that velocity at the entrance of the of the mesh (left-hand side) is 30 m/s. And the flow is 2-D, steady, inviscid and incompressible.

Comment: The mesh should go up to the non-perturbed region, thus $V_{\infty}=30 m/s$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "far away" phrase indicates that the airfoil does not disturb the velocity flow. In the image below ([source](http://www.mh-aerotools.de/airfoils/velocitydistributions.htm)), you can see how the airfoil affects the flow near the airfoil itself. But "far" above and below the airfoil, the flow isn't affected. This is your $v_\infty$ and, as [WolphramJonny](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/65081/wolphram-jonny) points out in the comments, this is equal to your $v_{in}=30$ m/s.

[image]