# Boundary conditions of stream function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, numerical-method

I have to do an problem about solving numerically the flow that goes under an airfoil. The airfoil has a flap deployed downwards and I need to solve the mesh that it's under the airfoil.

I have drawn the scheme of the problem which is the following:
[image]

I need to compute the values of stream function ( $\psi$), velocity (x and y components) and pressure coefficient at every node of the mesh (every node is a blue dot). the spacing between them is 0.1m on the x-direction and on the y-direction.

In order to compute stream function I have to discretize the Laplace equation:
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

However, I don't know what **boundary conditions for stream function** I must set in order to obtain 30 m/s at the left-hand side, and 60 m/s at the right-hand side.

I did the problem once but I mistook in the result because of the $\psi$ boundary conditions. So, I need to know what they would be on the **upper** wall, at the **entrance** (left side), at the **exit** and at the **lower part** (free stream). Or you could told me how to compute them at every part.

Comment: Related by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154252/

Comment: Looks like [Dirichlet boundaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_boundary_condition) at (1,:) and (16,:) for the velocities. How do those relate to $\psi$?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but could it be a linear variation? @KyleKanos

Comment: The question meant to ask, *How do the velocities, $u,\,v$, relate to $\psi$?* This is a straight-forward definition that you should know immediately. If not, you need to go back to your textbook and find the answer.

Comment: Oh okay I know that, I just did not understand the question. $u=\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}$ and $v=-\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$, but how can I get the BC from these expressions? @KyleKanos

Comment: Do you know what boundary conditions are? Really not trying to be glib, but @KyleKanos gave you literally everything you need in his comment. And your response contains everything you need.

Comment: Maybe just to give a little more help -- there are two types of boundary conditions. Dirichlet, which Kyle gave you a link to, and [Neumann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition) which could be more appropriate here depending on how you are going about the solution process.

Comment: @user3780731 Hi, I have a problem similar to yours. Did you manage to find a solution?